# What is the meaning of "We have outfoxed the fox, which makes us very bloody foxy." in the TV series Misfits?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the episode 5 of season 1 of the British television series [Misfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_(TV_series)) the character Nathan Young says:

> We have outfoxed the fox, which makes us very bloody foxy.

[Transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=misfits&episode=s01e05).

What does it mean in the context? My understanding after searching is something along the lines of:

> We were more clever deceiving them than them to us, which makes us way more deceitful than them.

Is that interpretation correct or is there something different in the context?

Asking since Kelly Bailey laughed when he said that, to which Nathan said:

> You like that, huh? Yeah.

[YouTube episode (clip from 5:31 to 5:38)](https://youtu.be/TWi1Vykz11s?t=331).

---

My search results are below with the parts that I believe matter.

Definition of [outfox](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fox#h47367895681900):

> **TRANSITIVE VERB**
>   *informal*
>   Defeat or deceive (someone) by being more clever or cunning than they are; outwit.

Definition of [fox<sup>1</sup>](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bloody#h70150449908220):

> **NOUN**
>   **2** A cunning or sly person.

Definition of [bloody<sup>2</sup>](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foxy):

> **ADJECTIVE**
>   *British*
>   **1** *informal attributive* Used to express anger, annoyance, or shock, or simply for emphasis.

Definition of [foxy](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cunning):

> **ADJECTIVE**
>   **1.1** *informal* Cunning or sly in character.

Definition of [cunning](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/deceit):

> **ADJECTIVE**
>   **1** Having or showing skill in achieving one's ends by deceit or evasion.

Definition of [deceit][10]:

> **NOUN**
>   The action or practice of deceiving someone by concealing or misrepresenting the truth.

Comment: Yes, but please look at the guidelines for quality questions given in the Help Center. Dictionary definitions, linked and attributed, are required (and would provide your answer).

Comment: Foxy can mean "sexually attractive", (as in Hendrix's Foxy Lady) and that's probably the intended meaning here.

Comment: Yes, the first two uses of *fox* meant *sly and cunning*, but the last use of *fox* (in *foxy*) means *sexy*. It's a pun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm a little bit lost. Where in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you mean the searching part, I did googled `define outfoxed`, `define fox`, `define bloody` and `define foxy`.

Comment: But this is reasonable research, and reasonable research should be shown, with a link and attribution.

Comment: You should tell us (in the question) what you searched for, what you found, and why that didn't answer your question. If you do those things but don't tell us it looks like you haven't spend any effort trying to find the answer on your own. Often while doing the research for your question you will find the answer on your own and not need to post it.

Comment: @CJDennis Oh. Well I wasn't aware that was required since many similar questions didn't seemed to have that problem. I did wrote my understanding of the phrase in the question which is the result of my search, just wasn't sure if that's what it trully means or if I missed something or so. I can add links to the lexico.com definitions. My question isn't what the definitions mean but the phrase in the context.

Comment: @CJDennis I have edited the question to better reflect what you have pointed out. If there's still something missing do let me know.

Comment: The research now shown is fine. But why doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added a little more to it. The way it's said and taken it seems to have some other hidden meaning or something that makes it funny or only understood by some. As in, that it conveys something more than my interpretation.

Comment: It could be an in-house joke, peculiar to 'Misfits', which would make it an unsuitable question on ELU. The place to check for non-standard usages, standing jokes and the like would be at source: the producers, or program website.

Comment: "Foxy" as used here very clearly means "tricky", with a connotation of "clever". To "outfox the fox" means "to trick the trickster" and is a reasonably popular figure of speech, playing on the popular metaphor of a fox for a coy and cunning person. The word "foxy" can also be a synonym for "sexy" and is likely the joke here. Tricking the trickster makes them sexy. Not a great joke but then British comedies have a certain historic tradition of cheap, low ball jokes.

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding is correct.

**To outfox** [something/someone]: to be more cunning [than something/someone]; to outwit.

A **fox** = an animal traditionally seen as being cunning.

**Foxy** = (i) crafty, cunning. (ii)  U.S. slang. Of a woman: attractive, desirable, pretty; sexy.

Comment: The downvote is really because this LMGTFY (let me google that for you) offering is inappropriate on ELU. But the downvote is totally justified as your answer is either lacking authoritative references, or lacking (legally!) required linked attributions. And this is not the first time.

Answer (score -1):

‘**As cunning as a fox’** - simile

If you are clever enough to outwit, or trick, the fox, then you must be clever indeed, for a fox is an animal traditionally known for its cunning or wit.

The sentence means that you must be more cunning than he. Making you - ‘foxier than a fox!’

Outwit means ‘to get the better of’ or ‘to outsmart’ meaning to defeat by being more clever than.

I suggest you stay away from the word ‘deceive’ when trying to understand this sentence - although deceit may be a part of ‘cunning’ - *cunning* is the traditional behaviour attributed to the fox, at least in the UK.

Cunning, and sly. Cunning means ‘cleverly pushing forward one’s own best interests’ and sly means ‘clever in a sneaky, secretly self-interested way’.

Consider the fox in Pinnoccio, in the cartoon - one of the two sneaky characters trying to lead Pinoccio astray, is a fox. Displaying ‘cunning behaviour’ - self-interest.

The idea that ‘foxy’ is also ‘sexy’ is fairly modern, ushered in perhaps by Jimi Hendrix as commenters have suggested - however that emanated from the US and only caught on from around the 80s/90s in the UK to my memory (I’m from the UK).

Another example of this kind of sentence: ‘An idea so cunning, that you could stick a tail on it, and call it a weasel!’ Says Rowan Atkinson the comedian in ‘Blackadder’. The weasel being another animal known for cunning. Again, likening ‘a very clever thing’ to an animal also known for its cunning.

*As cunning as a fox* is a simile, in English. The fox is also depicted as ‘cunning’ in stories such as Aesop’s fables.

**Meaning: ‘we are cleverer than the fox - which makes us very clever indeed!’**

Definition: Cunning 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cunning

Simile: As cunning as a fox
https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/figures-similes-list.htm

Definition: Outwit 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outwit

Fables, The Fox and the Crow, Aesop
https://literarydevices.net/fable/

Pinnoccio Fox character ‘Honest John’
https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Honest_John

Rowan Atkinson as Edmund Blackadder ‘call it a weasel’
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092324/characters/nm0000100